# How to use an animated spiral as mask to reveal other objects?

Tags: animation, mesh, masking

I'm trying to use a complex shape as a mask to reveal what's within it. I tried using the Build modifier, but for this complex shape its not working, its just starting from from random vertices.

So I made my curve and animated it and works fine as it animates from starting point to the end point.
I tried using it as smart Boolean but its not working, the spheres just disappear. Is there a way I can use this curve as a mask since the animation works well for what I need?

https://streamable.com/4xz1xn

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide the blend file?

Comment: Here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=oRBOMsVo" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/oRBOMsVo/)

Comment: i a "normal" case i thought you just have to sort elements in mesh and then the build modifier would built it in that way. But weird enough - it does not work :( i have no idea why.

Comment: I tried it with the build modifier but there method is way to complex for me to understand having to use some sort of code or other way which seems very complex for me.

Comment: I've tried another method which is tedious. I made the usual cube and scaled it, and gave it loop cuts, then I selected the Sort elements method so when
adding the build modifier the animation starts from the selected point. then I placed it horizontally and starting to deform it trying to make it a spiral 
grabbing each section of the vertices rotating them in a circular  direction. Then added the solidify modifier and made the smart Boolean operation 
and the masking starting to reveal each sphere in a sequential mode. 

But I'm sure there's a better approach to this method.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1s4Qs4G

https://streamable.com/ggq0yi